# Regex for JavaScript to validate username

Tags: javascript

I need help with making a javascript regex to validate a username. I found this regex and made some changes with the little knowledge I have

```
([0-9a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][0-9_.-]*){3}$
```

but I can't get what I want. When I try

```
_*2h4wk.e3
```

It passes in regex101.com, but it should not since it contains an asterisk

I need a regex that:

- must have at least 3 or more alpha characters (a-zA-Z) in any order, does not have to be consecutive
- allows numbers in any order (note: numbers are not required, but optional)
- allows only a hyphen, underscore, and dot in any order (note: any other symbols are not allowed)
- has min of 5 characters, max of 20

Comment: Simple question: why put restrictions on it at all? Just accept all printable Unicode as username, a regex like this in 2023 is just being mean to your users. You don't actually care, the computers certainly don't care, just let people use real usernames.

Comment: What about this? ^(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){3})(?!.*[^0-9A-Za-z_\-\.]).{5,20}$

Comment: @CodingNinja that looks like an answer, in which case you should probably post it as such with an explanation of what the various parts do (with a regex101 link to show it off for added usefulness)

Comment: Given you're using JavaScript, are you constrained to regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assert 5-20 of the allowed characters, and then match at least 3 chars a-zA-Z

```
^(?=[\w.-]{5,20}$)(?:[\d_.-]*[a-zA-Z]){3}[\w.-]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[\w.-]{5,20}$)` Assert 5-20 of the allowed characters
- `(?:[\d_.-]*[a-zA-Z]){3}` Match 3 times a-zA-Z followed by optional digits `_` `.` `-`
- `[\w.-]*` Match optional word chars or `.` or `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5QzBeX/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?=[\w.-]{5,20}$)(?:[\d_.-]*[a-z]){3}[\w.-]*$/i;
[
  "_*2h4wk.e3",
  "abcde",
  "_.-ab----c",
  "@#$ @2 #@$@#$",
  "........a.................b......c",
  "....a...MM"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${regex.test(s)} --> ${s}`)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

- must have at least 3 or more alpha characters (a-zA-Z) in any order, does not have to be consecutive
  `([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3}`
- allows numbers in any order (note: numbers are not required, but optional)
  `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`
- allows only a hyphen, underscore, and dot in any order (note: any other symbols are not allowed)
  `^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*$`
- has min of 5 characters, max of 20
  `^.{5,20}$`

Resulting in `/^(?=([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3})[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{5,20}$/`